# React delay consecutive calls to query onMouseEnter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react antd component that uses the onMouseEnter prop that calls a query to my api. I want to make it so that when onMouseEnter first calls the api its works fine...then if the user somehow keeps moving the mouse over the component, not to call the api that many times. Maybe a timer between consecutive calls to the api so the network doesnt get flooded with calls.

This is the antd component very simple:

```
 <Select onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter} />
```

This is the function executed everytime the onMouseEnter is called:

```
const handleMouseEnter = () => {
      refetchQueries();
    }
```

Basically dont do consectuive calls if the user accidentally enters the component 5 times a couple seconds. And Im not sure if debounce would work here because from what I understood debounce calls the function x many seconds after the last time it was invoked.

Comment: Look up what a debouncer and a throttler is: https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/

Comment: I tried using throttle but it still calls the function after x amount of seconds even if the user mouse doesnt enter the component for in that moment thats why I said I dont think it has to do with throttler and debounce @Dominik

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new boolean `state` and set this state when `onMouseEnter` triggered and with `setTimeout` you can reset this state to initial condition and then you can use this state like condition to trigger `onMouseEnter` event like this

```
<Select onMouseEnter={ () => { this.state.isNotActive && {
                     setState({isNotActive: false}); 
                     handleMouseEnter; 
                     setTimeout(() => { setState({isNotActive: true})}, 5000);
                      } } } />
```